# Is it possible to open a JQuery lightbox from a Flash movie?

Tags: jquery, flash

Is it possible to open a JQuery lightbox from a Flash movie?

Answer (score 3):

Try [Calling any JS lightbox from Flash using jQuery](http://www.thetruetribe.com/jquery/1-jquery-api/87-calling-any-js-lightbox-from-flash-using-jquery)

Flash:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, external, false, 0, true);
function external(evt:MouseEvent):void {
 ExternalInterface.call("external", "lightbox/photos/image1.jpg");
}
```

Javascript:

```
function external(path) { // pass in the correct path to the function so we only need one <A> for infinite amount of calls from  flash              
// if the lightbox does not exist we will make it               
 if ($('a#lightbox').length == 0) {                 
  $("body").append("</A><A id="lightbox" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -9999px;" href="http://www.thetruetribe.com/+path+">calling js lightbox from flash</A>");                
  $('a#lightbox').lightBox();           
// if it already exists but the path is different we will set the new path              
 } else if ($('a#lightbox').attr("href") != path) {                 
  $('a#lightbox').attr("href", path);           
 }      
// now we will simulate the click here.             
 $('a#lightbox').trigger("click");      
}
```

Or you could port flashLightBoxInjector [Start Lightbox from Flash](http://www.bram.us/projects/flashlightboxinjector) a PrototypeJS class to the jQuery framework without too much trouble if your a somewhat confident in writing javascript

Comment: Thanks man...I also thought about using ExternalInterface.call. But it's only in AS3 right?  I want to add the jquery thing to a code written in AS2.  Any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it.

To call a javascript function doIt(), you write:

```
getURL("javascript:doIt()");
```

But really, if you are having to do that, there might be better ways to solve your problem.

jrh